# Problem with date format

Tags: openfda

I'm getting some problems with the format dates on openfda. Is there an existing method to format or process to show on a chart?

Comment: What is the exact nature of the 'problems'? What language are you working with? Etc. Imagine you are reading your own question and then try to answer it.

Comment: Can you post an example, I would be happy to help?

Comment: Here is a [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15952652/3961519) about dates in JSON, which is the format in which you'll get your openFDA data after a request. Depending on the language you are to build something you can find a library to help you manipulate that data,like [_moment.js_ for javascript](http://momentjs.com/). Other languages, like python, will have their own libraries.